# Post on others' Facebook fan page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am able to post on users wall of my application, now I want to post the Facebook pages created by others. For example, suppose I want to post feeds on Coca Cola page through my application.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The same API is used to post on the page's wall-

```
$facebook->api("/PAGE_ID/feed" , {params}, "POST");
```

**Note:** Not on every page you can post on their wall. It depends on the privacy settings of the page .

For eg, If they don't allow such actions, you'll get the respnse error as-

> The target user has not authorized this action